# While converting a character to Date format in R, the result is showing as NA

Tags: r

I have a vector of class 'character' and want to convert it into Date format in single command. I tried the below command but it is converting only few and rest are resulting in NA.

dt1 <- c("02/07/10", "02/23/10", "02/08/10", "02/14/10", "02/10/10")
dt2 <- as.Date(dt1)

I expect the output to be in Date format but the actual output is
"0002-07-10" NA           "0002-08-10" NA           "0002-10-10"
Can someone tell me what is wrong that i am doing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `format` argument i.e. `as.Date(dt1, format = "%m/%d/%y")`. assuming it is in day-month-year order

Answer (score 2):

The function `as.Date()` has a the `format` argument that must be used in order to instruct the machin on how to convert from date to string.
You must specify to R that "/" is used as a separator, and that the format is *dd mm yy*. R alone doesn't know that, and I think that is the reason why it returns wrong results.
You can learn to manipulate date formats [in this help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/as.Date).